# How can I gather information about exception?

Tags: java, debugging

Since I work in project also in maintenance team I have pretty often deal with same exceptions which occurs pretty often (in the same place) but there are insufficient amount of information in stacktrace about them. Which causes situation where even if it's very often I cannot do anything about them because cause is unknown.

So I was wondering if there are some tools which would allow to gather more information about context (probably by connecting somehow JVM).

Is this place where I should use these guys:
jinfo, jhat, jmap, jsadebugd, jstack?

Or maybe there are some more handy/more powerful/(call it) ways?

What I would expect:

- dump values of variables (in invoked method and if possible in other methods in stacktrace)
- solution doesn't change code itself
- checking if some other defined methods was invoked before exception occured

Comment: what about analyzing the stack trace/msg?

Comment: The tools to use depend on the type of the exception. There's no single ultimate tool that would help you fix all kinds of errors in your application.

Comment: as I told analyzing stack trace and message is insufficient to proceed

Comment: You'd get a lot more help if you actually said which exception you're getting, instead of hoping for some magic wand that solves all your problems.

Comment: Exceptions maybe different as an example I had NullPointerException in entity on field annotated with @NotNull. This entity was taken from DB and there was not found place were setter could change this value.

But basically it doesn't matter I've seen many "mysterious" exceptions and I would like to have tools to fight them.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace provides you with the exact line of code where the problem occurred along with a (hopefully) useful message to explain the problem, which *should* be enough to identify the problem.

Generally, if it's not, the best thing to do is to modify the code in the problematic area, to give you more information. That might be to log the state of variables just before the line where the exception occurs, in all cases (not just when there's an exception), or to increase the amount of information provided when the exception does occur.

Alternatively, if there is more than one thing happening on the line where the exception occurs, you could split the code there into multiple lines, which will cause the line number in all subsequent exceptions to be more helpful, for example, if you have a line like this:

```
Foo myFoo = myBar.getBaz().getFoo();
```

and you get a `NullPointerException` on that line, you might not be able to identify whether `myBar` is null, or whether its `getBaz()` method returns null. If you split that into:

```
Baz myBaz = myBar.getBaz();
Foo myFoo = myBaz.getFoo();
```

the next time you encounter the same `NullPointerException` the line number will give you a better clue as to what is null.

Comment: This assumes we have plenty of time. In project I work for releases are not on daily basis and gathering information in such manner would take very unreasonable amount of time. That's why I thought about remote debugging tools in order to change my "code" for investigation much more often then releases come up.